# Split Time Range into Half Hour Each Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that look like this

[image: Initial data set]

And i want to split it so the data becomes like this

[image: Splitted data set]

Any vba code idea? Thank you!

I have tried this code from user in another forum but it only show 1 hour time interval. Could you please help me to make it become 30 min time interval?

```
Sub sample()
Dim bufF As String, bufT As String, NO As String, name As String, 
day As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastR1 As Long, LastR2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x() As String, y() As String, cnt As Long
Set ws1 = Sheets("data") '<--change the sheet name
Set ws2 = Sheets("result") '<--change the sheet name

With ws1
    LastR1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastR1
        NO = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        name = .Cells(i, 2).Value
        bufF = InStr(Format(.Cells(i, 3).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), " ")
        bufF = Mid(Format(.Cells(i, 3).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), bufF 
        + 1, 2)
        bufT = InStr(Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), " ")
        bufT = Mid(Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), bufT 
        + 1, 2)
        day = Format(.Cells(i, 3).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy ")
            If bufT = "00" Then bufT = 24
            With ws2
                LastR2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                ReDim x(bufT * 1 - bufF * 1)
                ReDim y(bufT * 1 - bufF * 1)

                For j = bufF * 1 To bufT * 1 - 1
                    x(cnt) = day & j & ":00"
                    y(cnt) = NO & "-" & j
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                Next
                .Range(.Cells(LastR2 + 1, 1), .Cells(LastR2 + cnt, 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(y)
                .Range(.Cells(LastR2 + 1, 3), .Cells(LastR2 + cnt, 3)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(x)
                .Range(.Cells(LastR2 + 1, 2), .Cells(LastR2 + cnt, 2)).Value = name
            End With
            cnt = 0
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could put all the data into an array and then  cycle through the array outputting everything into your desired format. Keep in mind this is not a code writing website but a site where users will help others with *specific* problems they are having with their code. Perhaps have a read of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info on writing better quality questions.

Comment: Could you please help me writing the code? I have tried but still cannot get the desired format

Comment: I can help depending on what you have already tried. Edit your question to include what code you have already written (whether it works or not) and from there I (we) can see what we can do to help.

Comment: I have posted the code, would you please help me? Thank you

Comment: Your `BufF` variable is not a number. When I set up the data per your image, `BufF` results to "Pa". Then the code gets an error when trying to multiply that by 1.

Comment: It's a bit hard to work out what your code is supposed to be doing without effective variable names. I have no idea what `BufT` or `BufF` are supposed to be without stepping through the code or adding a break point to evaluate what it is and work it out from there. As a tip you should always name your variables something descriptive and relevant to the data/value it represents.

Comment: Actually i get it from a user in another forum, i tried the code and it actually works but it show 1 hour interval only. Can you please help me to modify the code? It's okay if you need to change the variable name.

Comment: My comment was more to point out, you should change your variable names otherwise it's difficult to debug code. I've found your issue and will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try  something like this:

```
Sub sample()
Dim bufF As String, bufT As String, NO As String, name As String, day As String, Min As String, Min2 As String
Dim i As Long, j As Single, LastR1 As Long, LastR2 As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x() As String, y() As String, cnt As Long
Set ws1 = Sheets("data") '<--change the sheet name
Set ws2 = Sheets("result") '<--change the sheet name

With ws1
    LastR1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastR1
        NO = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        name = .Cells(i, 2).Value
        bufF = InStr(Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), " ")
        bufF = Mid(Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), bufF + 1, 2)
        bufT = InStr(Format(.Cells(i, 5).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), " ")
        bufT = Mid(Format(.Cells(i, 5).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), bufT + 1, 2)
        Min = InStr(Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), ":")
        Min = Mid(Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), Min + 1, 2)
        Min2 = InStr(Format(.Cells(i, 5).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), ":")
        Min2 = Mid(Format(.Cells(i, 5).Value, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), Min2 + 1, 2)
        day = Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy ")
            If bufT = "00" Then bufT = 24
            With ws2
                LastR2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                ReDim x(bufT * 2 - bufF * 2)
                ReDim y(bufT * 2 - bufF * 2)
                If Min = "30" Then bufF = bufF + 0.5
                If Min2 = "30" Then bufT = bufT + 0.5
                For j = bufF * 1 To bufT * 1 - 0.5 Step 0.5
                If j = Int(j) Then
                    x(cnt) = day & j & ":00"
                    y(cnt) = NO & "-" & j
                    cnt = cnt + 1

                Else
                    x(cnt) = day & Int(j) & ":30"
                    y(cnt) = NO & "-" & j
                    cnt = cnt + 1

                End If
                Next j
                .Range(.Cells(LastR2 + 1, 1), .Cells(LastR2 + cnt, 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(y)
                .Range(.Cells(LastR2 + 1, 3), .Cells(LastR2 + cnt, 3)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(x)
                .Range(.Cells(LastR2 + 1, 2), .Cells(LastR2 + cnt, 2)).Value = name
            End With
            cnt = 0
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried the code you guys gave and it works! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your existing code, this is tested and works. Readability is much easier and with descriptive variable names it's easier to see what each line is doing.

***Note:*** This will only find half hour intervals between 1 hour. If for example the start time is 09:00 and the end time is 11:00 it would only return the times for 09:00 and 09:30.

```
Sub RevisedSample()
Dim myName As String 'Name could be confused with the Excel '.Name' property.
Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
Dim Activity As String, Detail As String
Dim LastRowSource As Long, LastRowDestination As Long, LoopCountSource As Long, LoopCountDestination As Long
Dim ThirtyMinInterval As Boolean: ThirtyMinInterval = False 'Explicitly assigning False to variable
Dim StringStartTime As String, StringEndTime As String
Dim Time As String
Dim TimeArray As Variant
Dim ArrayCounter As Long

Set SourceSheet = Sheets("Sheet1") '<--change the sheet name
Set DestinationSheet = Sheets("Sheet2") '<--change the sheet name

With SourceSheet
    LastRowSource = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For LoopCountSource = 2 To LastRowSource
        myName = .Cells(LoopCountSource, 1).Value
        Activity = .Cells(LoopCountSource, 2).Value
        StartTime = .Cells(LoopCountSource, 4).Value
        EndTime = .Cells(LoopCountSource, 5).Value

        If DateDiff("n", StartTime, EndTime) > 30 Then
            ThirtyMinInterval = True

            StringStartTime = CStr(StartTime)
            StringEndTime = CStr(EndTime)

            Time = InStr(Format(StringStartTime, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), " ")
            Time = Mid(Format(StringStartTime, "ddmmyyyy hh:mm"), Time + 1, 2)
            Time = Time & ":30"
            StringEndTime = Format(Mid(StringStartTime, 1, 8), "dd/mm/yyyy") & " " & Time

            ReDim TimeArray(1 To 2)
            TimeArray(1) = StartTime
            TimeArray(2) = CDate(StringEndTime)
        End If

        Detail = .Cells(LoopCountSource, 3).Value

        With DestinationSheet
            LastRowDestination = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If ThirtyMinInterval = True Then
                ArrayCounter = 1
                For LoopCounterDestination = LastRowDestination To LastRowDestination + (UBound(TimeArray) - 1)
                    .Range("A" & LoopCounterDestination).Value = myName
                    .Range("B" & LoopCounterDestination).Value = TimeArray(ArrayCounter)
                    .Range("C" & LoopCounterDestination).Value = Activity
                    .Range("D" & LoopCounterDestination).Value = Detail

                    ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
                Next LoopCounterDestination
            Else
                    .Range("A" & LastRowDestination).Value = myName
                    .Range("B" & LastRowDestination).Value = StartTime
                    .Range("C" & LastRowDestination).Value = Activity
                    .Range("D" & LastRowDestination).Value = Detail
            End If
        End With
        ThirtyMinInterval = False
    Next LoopCountSource
End With

End Sub
```

Screenshots of Source Sheet (`Sheet1`) and Destination Sheet(`Sheet2`):

### Sheet1:

[image: Source data on Sheet1]

### Sheet2:

[image: Destination data on Sheet2]

Comment: Hello, i make some modification on the table so the start date and finish date containing formula like this =TEXT(DATE(M2,L2,K2),"dd/mm/yyyy ")&TEXT([Start Time],"hh:mm"). M2, L2, K2 contains day, month, year respectively. Any idea how to modify the macro?

Comment: It would be best to ask a new question with all the relevant information in it (that way others can look at it and answer it too!).

Comment: Okay, will try it. Thank you!

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471898/split-time-range-to-half-hour-interval here i already posted the question